# If you take Markarth as a stormcloak, does your bounty from when it was imperial-held go away?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just did the Eltry quest and ended up with the corrupt guards trying to take me in. I killed them as well as the other guards who tried to jail me when I walked out. I also killed the ones in the guard tower and now I have a 13,000 gold bounty on me in the reach right now. If I take the city with the Stormcloaks, does my bounty get reset to 0?